# Angular mat-tree: How to insert new items on top?

Tags: angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 2 Tree component. In the provided example, when you add a new item, the edit box is displayed at the bottom, how can I add it to at the first position, so we can always see the added edit box as in my use case I can add many new items.

See https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjyykvkrdll?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ChecklistDatabase` class, change `insertItem()` method from a `.push` to a `.splice`

```
/** Add an item to to-do list */
  insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (parent.children) {
      //parent.children.push({item: name} as TodoItemNode);
      parent.children.splice(0,0,{item: name} as TodoItemNode);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifr2tc?embed=1&file=app/tree-checklist-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

In my code, i use unshift()

```
insertItem(parent: FileNode, name: string) {
const child = <FileNode>{ name: name,'parent_id': parent.parent_id};

if (parent.children) {
  parent.children.unshift(child);
  this.dataChange.next(this.data);
} else {
  parent.children = [];
  parent.children.unshift(child);
  this.dataChange.next(this.data);
}
```